# Spring 3 MVC - Browsers think my downloads are .htm files

Tags: java, spring-mvc, download, spring-3

I implemented a download controller in a Spring 3 framework webapp which is supposed to be be called to initiate a Open/Save dialog when called.

It does indeed initiate the Open/Save dialog and Save works fine. When I click Open however, it appends a ".htm" to my file name and opens it all wrong. Why?

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("download/downloadFile")
    @ResponseBody
    public byte[] downloadFile(@RequestParam String fileID, HttpServletResponse response) {

        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        File file = getFileByID(fileID);                       

        byte[] bytes = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(file);

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");     
        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);

        return bytes;
    }
```

When I see the Response Headers I see the content type is text/html, like it ignored my setting it to application/octet-stream!

```
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store
Connection  close
Content-Disposition attachment; filename="test.txt"
Content-Length  22071
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Tue, 05 Feb 2013 21:12:20 GMT
Expires Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache/2.2.10 (Linux/SUSE)
X-Powered-By    Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
X-UA-Compatible IE=8, chrome=1
```

Is it perhaps because of the way I setup my Spring MVC in web.xml?

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Where everything is mapped to a URL ending in ".html" and the browser is looking at that?

Comment: Is `getFileByID(fileID)` a repository method? What is actually returned by `file.getName()`? What do you see when you trace it? Do `System.out.println(file.getName());` and see what is produced on the server console.

Comment: It is a properietary method to return a java.io.File object, so the getName() method is from Java's IO library and it returns "test.txt" (but txt files isnt the best sample, when I try images/PDF files I see the correct file name)

Comment: What headers did you specify on the client side? They should be `headers: { 
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                    },` as you're dealing with JSON. The response headers are appropriate as you have specified.

Comment: Can you try removing the *.html from the url-pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two styles of producing response. Writing to response directly, and asking Spring to write the return value of the method to the response body. You should stick to one, as you have it currently, the framework is overwriting the response content-type. In general you can mention the content type of the response as an attribute `produces` of the `@RequestMapping` annotation. However since in this case you also want to write the content disposition header, I would suggest using a custom view, instead of `@ResponseBody` annotation.

In your custom view class, set the headers you want, and then stream the bytes to the response output stream yourself.

Hope this helps.